# Is unreachable code safe to remove? (-Wunreachable-code)

Tags: c

I have an older program that was built with clang via CFLAGS="-Wunreachable-code" and it's displaying some warnings on certain switch(), on a break; where it's saying it's 'will never be executed', is it safe to simply remove the unreachable code, or is -Wunreachable-code beta in nature?

Specifically, it's giving warnings on a few functions, ie: return -1 after a previous return, and breaks inside of a switch()

Comment: It's code will never be executed through normal operations... hence the warnings. Why not?

Comment: The unreachability might be a programming error. Best to investigate what the code is supposed to do. It was put there for some reason after all.

Comment: I could never find a general answer to why it's not included with -Wall, and a thread suggested it's beta in nature.

Comment: > This option is **not made part of -Wall** because in a debugging version of a program there is often substantial code which checks correct functioning of the program and is, hopefully, unreachable because the program does work. Another common use of unreachable code is to provide behavior which is selectable at compile-time. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.6/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read the code, understand it, and if the code marked unreachable really is unreachable and it isn't unreachable because of a logic error, then you can just remove it. If you haven't read the code and understood it, then it isn't safe to modify it no matter what the compiler says.

Answer (score 2):

I just found following link:

http://old.nabble.com/gcc--Wunreachable-code-option-td31698329.html

That option has been removed because it is unstable.
Check the mailing thread for details

Comment: That seems to only apply to gcc and not clang.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that warning is conservative, i.e. it won't be given unless the compiler is sure it is unreachable code.